N-colorability bounds on grid maps
I currently have the problem of coloring a map with regions that are defined on a square grid.
Every region is a connected set of cells on this grid, such that the cells connect either horizontally or vertically to each other, e.g: Tetris pieces for regions of size four.
Since this is a restriction on normal maps, the conventional border graph is still planar and the grid map can always be 4-colored.
If one counts corner connections as borders, the neccesary number of colors required to color a map is in general not bounded anymore, since arbitrarily many regions (N) can meet at one corner, introducing a complete border graph of order N which needs N colors.
However, this is not the case with such grid regions.
Here, at most 4 regions can meet at a corner.
Is there a upper bound on the number of colors k required to color such a graph?
I am able to construct the following example requiring at least k=6 colors, but have not progressed further, since.
\begin{matrix}
\color{red}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{red}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{blue}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{blue}█\hspace{-1em}\\[-1em]
\color{red}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{orange}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{cyan}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{blue}█\hspace{-1em}\\[-1em]
\color{red}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{yellow}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{lime}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{blue}█\hspace{-1em}\\[-1em]
\color{red}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{red}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{blue}█\hspace{-1em} & \color{blue}█\hspace{-1em}
\end{matrix}
